# list of unique elements formed by concatenating permutations of initial lists

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I already asked the question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70968661/list-of-unique-elements-formed-by-concatenating-permutations-of-the-initial-list), but I thoughted more about the problem, and my question is now not about programming but graph theory.

I would like to combine several lists, the result must be a list of unique elements formed by concatenating permutations of the initial lists.

Here is an example:

I would like to combine these lists

```
[[0, 7], [2, 4], [0, 1, 7], [0, 1, 4, 7]]
```

The output I would like to obtain is e.g. this list

```
 [2, 4, 0, 7, 1]
```

Putting each unique element from all initial lists as nodes in a graph (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 4, and 7) and weighting the edges between two nodes with the number of occurrences of any permutation of these two nodes, I obtain a graph like this for this example[image]

My hypothesis now is, that the maximum weighted hamiltonian path is the solution (result list). For the examples I did, it was correct - but now I am searching for proof. I am not a mathematician/ computer scientist, I have no clue how to start to find such proof.

Comment: Does an output list need to contain all the elements that appear in the input? Are you looking for just any valid output, or the longest one, or do you need to generate all of them?

Comment: I am looking for the longest outputs

Comment: But actually, right now I am more interested if the hypothesis is correct or not, and if so why

Comment: Also, permuting one of the input lists in the output (or changing the order of concatenation) doesn't affect the validity of the output, right? It seems like you just need to determine which of the input lists are disjoint from each other and then choose a mutually disjoint collection of them to concatenate.

Comment: since the lists are in general not disjoint, I cannot change the order of concatenation. maybe I misunderstood you, can you explain it with my example

Comment: Permuting the input list [0,1,7] in the ouput [2, 4, 0, 7, 1], obviously is not allowed, since it can destroy the existence of the list [0,7]

Comment: I think your heuristic could produce a path that is not a valid output ordering. E.g. if the input is [[1,2],[2,3]] you'd output [1,2,3].

Comment: Oh, so every input list must appear (possibly permuted) as a sequence of consecutive elements in the output?

Comment: but [1,2,3] would be perfect

Comment: How do you form [1,2,3] by concatenating the input lists?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133905/discussion-between-nuemlouno-and-karl).

Comment: The statement you want to prove needs clarifications. Note that the permutation you got can be equivalently written as [1,2,4,0,7], whereas your graph has no edge {1,2}. On the other hand, the result permutation might include more than one cycle, which obviously makes the word "hamiltonian" inapropriate.